# No response from model. Codeigniter Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my first attempt at ajax and I am still new to CI as well. I have set up my MVC as it is below and am using a bookmarklet to call the js function. I know that the bookmarklet part of the program is working as I can hard code a `$('#source').val('Update Summary ID')` and have it update my field correctly. When I try to use an AJAX request, I am getting no response. I am using firebug to check the response and see no errors coming through as well. Let me know if I have set everything up correctly so far and what else I am missing. Thanks!

Controller:

```
    public function updatePajeFields(){
        $data['id'] = $this->mAutoPAJE->updatePajeFields();
        header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($data['id']);

    }
```

Model:

```
     public function updatePajeFields(){
         $row = $_POST['row'];
         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('pajeV2test');
         $this->db->where('paje_id', $row);

         $query = $this->db->get();
         return  $query->result_array();
      }
```

javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var data = {
             'row' :  prompt("What is the ID?  v4")
        }
    $.ajax({
         url: 'http://myurl',
         data: data,
         type: 'POST',
        success: function(responses) {
             $('#ticket').val(responses.researched_by);
             $('#source').val(responses.researched_by);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: what is the response of the ajax call you see in firebug?

Comment: The response is blank. I have tried a few other things with varying results. I wanted to make sure the call was making it to the controller first so I just added a basic echo in the function. The echo did not work until I added `dataType: 'jsonp'`. With this though my POST variable does not get passed to the model. Does that help any troubleshooting?.

Comment: for debugging I suggest you remove the json header from the controller, set the datatype in jquery to "text" and put console.log(responses) in your success callback, now if you managed to get an echo in the controller, add `var_dump($row)` in your model also I suggest you use CI's input class to retrieve the post value like this `$row = $this->input->post('row')`

Comment: Thanks koala! Setup like this, I do not receive any response or echo.

Comment: You do have your console open right? Do you still get the echo from your controller? another useful tip when debugging AJAX: you can go into Firebug's "Net" tab, click "XHR" and analyze the complete request and response headers

Comment: Yes, console is open. Nothing in Net tab either. The only unusual thing I notice is that the call inside the console is red instead of black when run clean. There is no specific error message though. Across from the POSt message it references `/jquery.min.js (line2)`

Comment: I'm not used to Firebug but I assume red means there was an error with the call, click the red link and check params, headers and response

Comment: yes, it usually means there was an error but no error noted. post, response, html tabs all blank. header had usual response.

Answer (score 0):

I think result_array will return an array so you would need something like `$results = $query->result_array(); $return $results[0];`. Alternatively you could use `$query->row();` which returns a single row.

[Query Results - CodeIgniter docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: Can you try `file_put_contents('log.txt', $this->db->_compile_select());` right before the `$this->db->get();` line? This should give you the exact query it's running. You can then see if the query is the problem (e.g. parameters are incorrect) or the data itself.

Comment: Where am I able to access the log.txt output from?

Comment: If PHP has write permission (which it should if your host is configured properly), it will be in the directory where your script is executing.

Comment: I am running this on localhost and don't see it in any log folders. Am I able to echo the results?

Comment: I guess you could always try to echo it and see the results in your browser's console.

As for the `log.txt` file, you should be able to find it in the `models` or `controllers` directory.